# How to group all the logs in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging, asp.net-web-api, serilog

I have one main mvc application that will call 3 web api applications and will write logs using `log.LogInformation()` for each method hit and each controller in the mvc project. I created a variable named `username` and have each of the logs to include that username at the end of the message. I.e. `log.LogInformation("You have hit the home page of the mvc project... {@Username}, username)`so at the end of every log message I am using `{@Username}` and passing `username`. I am wanting to group all the entire logs based on that variable `username`. Is there a way to group all the entire logs that get recorded to logger, starting from the mvc project to every web api project called? I am using `Serilog` to write the logs.

---

Follow up:

So after reading `Log scopes` and using `BeginScope` I could create another method in my mvc project in my last controller as so:

```
    public IActionResult GetAllLogs()
    {
        using (_logger.BeginScope("Gathering all the logs created for {@Username}", HomeController.username))
        {

        }
    }
```

So leaving it as will be able to gather all the logs from the mvc project that includes the web api projects logs? I wouldn't need to do anything inside of the `using()` statement?

Comment: You can check for `Log scopes` ([Read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#log-scopes)). With `BeginScope`, all the log statement inside the scope will have the property logged as custom property.

Comment: So with Log scope, you don't need to pass the property to nth function level. Since, property is logged as a custom property so you can do grouping, filtering e.t.c,.

Comment: Thank you! I was reading up on `Log scopes` with `BeginScope` I wouldn't need to do anything inside of the `using()` statement to gather all the logs since the `BeginScope` will gather all the logs? Please see my edited post @user1672994 I also saw this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerextensions.beginscope?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0 but it passes a property... you are saying I do not need to? How would it know that I want to use the variable `username` though?

Comment: @MarrkCo - I've posted as answer, Please check and let me know if you need any details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for Log scopes ([Read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#log-scopes)). With BeginScope, all the log statement inside the scope will have the property logged as custom property.

For ex:, the `Scope` is started at `SomeAPI` API which invokes Method1 -> Method2 -> Method3DoesTheLogging. Now till method `Method3DoesTheLogging`, no property need to be passed to be logged in log statement. The logging framework will automatically attached the custom property which were defined in `BeginScope.`

```
    public IActionResult SomeAPI()
    {
        using (_logger.BeginScope("Gathering all the logs created for {@Username}", HomeController.username))
        {
            Method1();
        }
    }
    
    public void Method1()
    {
        Method2();
    }
    
    public void Method2()
    {
        Method3DoesTheLogging();
    }
    
    public void Method3DoesTheLogging()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("This log statement will log the username automatically as custom property".);
    }
```

So with Log scope, you don't need to pass the property to nth function level. Since, property is logged as a custom property so you can do grouping, filtering e.t.c,

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. So wherever `.BeginScope()` is placed, that is where it will start to collect/group all the logs based on custom property? What if you do not know which method will be called during the start of the application? Because I see that you call up to the last method where the logging is happening? Also each of my method has a log, so when I would call a method within a method, I still would not need to pass the property?

Comment: `when I would call a method within a method, I still would not need to pass the property` - yes, no need. The begin scope defines the scope of custom property which will be logged by the log statement which are part of scope.

Comment: `What if you do not know which method will be called during the start of the application`- the concept is called structure logging where each method defines what to log; the other custom properties are logged based on the scope they are in. So suppose if a `method1` is called from two places, 1) which has scope and 2) which does not have scope. Then for #1, custom property will be logged for #2, the custom property will not logged.... So it would be a good pratice to start the start at the very function of invocation chain.

Comment: Another advantage of using Scope is that the nesting of scopes are also honored. You can play around with example for the sample created in [this](https://github.com/amigup/CleanArchitecture-For-AzureFunctionV3) repo.

Comment: I follow now, thank you for explaining it to me! :)